# creating SharePoint Application in 2013

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, web, host-header

I want to know how can i create web application with name local.xyz.com on port 80 in SharePoint 2013.

Please explain step by step procedure for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. make sure you have valid DNS entry for Local.xyz.com, A record entry for the DNS.
2. Service Account(domain Account) required which will run the App Pool of new Web App.
3. Now login on the Central Admin with Farm Admin account
4. go to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage web Application > from Ribbon Select New
5. Fill this form with proper values. Click Ok.
6. Now Create Root Level Site collection
7. Now Configure post thing i.e Object Cache settings, adding Default Content Access Account into Policy for web App,
8. If you using the customization, then apply now.
9. Make the appropriate changes to AAM.

Here are few links for your reference.

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/create-web-application-site-collection-sharepoint-2013-preview/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEWw1DrpLto

Comment: can u explain 5th step in detail..fill this form? i need to put 80 as port and DNs entry as host header?. also why i need to do anything in AAM?

Comment: Then you don't need to change the AAM.if you check 1st link, they explain all the options in step 5.

Comment: maybe you will also need to change the host file on the server disk drive.

Comment: AAM URL's are a mechanism that allows for a single site collection to be associated to multiple URLs. For this you can you AAM or Zones.. So ur present requirement wont requrie AAM/zones

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate access mapping for this. To configure this follow these articles:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814%28v=office.15%29.aspx)